# Setup static routes with Libreswan

Tags: linux, routing, azure, ipsec

We are using Libreswan to connect On-Premise network to Azure and BGP to advertise routes. But Azure BGP it's eBGP with 2 hops.

The use case it's:
a. setup IPSec tunnel
b. route Azure Peer IP via tunnel

My issue with B.

How to setup what routes must be defined as soon as tunnel is up?

Libreswan has configuration property for each connection leftupdown. It allows to re-define a very complex script to setup IPSec tunnel. Is there easiest way to define static routes for connection instead of patching _updown script?

Thanks

Comment: This is too vague to answer. Technically, Libreswan doesn't make any routing decisions. The routing table on each device, or on the network gateway does. Why do you mention BGP and then start talking about static routes? This is a good case for at least a brief diagram of your network setup, posting some sanitized config files, and providing some IP/Network addressing info and a clear description of what the problem is.

Comment: I've just describe my use case. And explain why I need to define one static route record  as soon as the tunnel is up.